# How do I read from a .txt file in Python and take specific things from it and put it in a tuple?

Tags: python-3.x, computer-science

So I want to read a .txt file in Python and take specific strings from the file and arrange them in a tuple. My code so far is:

```
opened_file = open(name_of_file, 'r')
file_list = []
candidate_dictionary = {'Donald Trump':'1st', 'Hillary Clinton':'2nd'}
for line in opened_file:
    file_list.append(line)
```

It obviously isn't complete yet, and that is why i'm stuck.

Comment: You can use `opened_file.readlines()` which will give you a list of all lines.

Answer (score 0):

Well first you could use file_list=opened_file.readlines() rather than a for loop. But to answer your question you could use line.find("search key") this will return a number >=0 if the string "search key" is found in the line. If it is not in the line it will return a -1.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm

Comment: so i get: 
opened_file = open(name_of_file, 'r')
    file_list = [ ]
    candidate_dictionary = {'Donald Trump':'1st', 'Hillary Clinton':'2nd'}
    for line in opened_file:
        file_list.append(line)
        line.find('Donald Trump')
    return line

This returns '<<<EOT'.

The .txt file is: 

Donald Trump:
791697302519947264,1477604720,Ohio USA,Twitter for iPhone,5251,1895
Join me live in Springfield, Ohio!
<<<EOT

But I want to put 'Donald Trump' in a tuple.

I want the tuple to look like ('Donald Trump', 'Join me live in Springfield, Ohio!', '5251', '1895')

Comment: @ArsalanAli was that a question to my post? Not sure what you are asking.